# Errors in maven Struts2 project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, struts2, struts2-jquery

### [image]

Eclipse displays errors in a Maven project. How can I fix it? 
It seems that project works as it should.

Maven dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-jquery-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-jquery-grid-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The jars downloaded from these artifacts should be on the classpath of the project Build Path. Subfolders aren't on the classpath, so eclipse can't find TLDs  there. Configure the build path by adding project or external jars to the build classpath.  You can see [How to generate eclipse configuration from maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15547226/573032).

Comment: why should I add this jar to the project if the remaining lifted by maven yourself? especially because yesterday everything was fine with the project. also, for some reason, Eclipse has already found _struts-jquery-tags_. this _mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=3.4.2_ command gives BUILD FAILURE

Comment: Read the above, BTW do you have a problem with maven?

Comment: I'm definitely new to Maven... You want to say that this jar _struts2-jquery-grid-plugin_ is located in the subfolder for struts2-jquery-plugin? 
It's not very convenient that some jar files must be added manually. Why we added dependenci in pom.xml for next: **<dependency>
<groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
<artifactId>struts2-jquery-grid-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.7.1</version>
</dependency>** if we must put this jar manualy into buid path?

Comment: ...again, we do not add to build path _struts2-jquery-plugin_ jar because it was resolwed by Maven, but manually added this jar _struts2-jquery-grid-plugin_, it's kinda strange, isn't it?

Comment: you know, it's not funny, in a good way :) because I deleted the project from Eclipse and imported it again, and this %&@&^* dependency appeared as needed

Comment: I don't know how do you use maven with eclipse may be with m2eclipse plugin but eclipse project configuration should be synchronized with maven configuration. The maven dependencies are downloaded to the local repository, which you can reference if you follow the link and update you eclipse project configuration. You can do it in many ways which is a good way is up to you.

Comment: Then you should be proficient with the maven development. Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25062089/573032).

Comment: thks, for now the progect seems ok. doesn't even show any warnings :)

Answer (score -1):

Try /struts2-jquery-tags instead of /struts-jquery-tags. Missed the '2' in struts.

Comment: The S2 jQuery tags don't use `struts2` as part of the tag URI, just like the S2 base tags don't. This is documented in the jQuery tag library docs, btw, https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery